# Maintaning my choices on GridView Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, checkbox

I have this Module in my project in which I have 2 gridviews. One is for the Main MenuModule and the other one is for it's subMenu. I created a List so that when a row on my Main Menu Module has been checked and it has a corresponding submenu, it will show on the SubMenu Gridview.

Now, I can see my SubMenuGridview when I get back to that page (I used session), but I noticed that the checkbox I ticked were all gone.

My problem was on how can my page remember the checkboxes I checked, both from my Main Menu Module gridview and from my Submenu gridview.

```
protected void cbxSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubMenuGrid.DataSource = null;
    SubMenuGrid.DataBind();

    Business.SubMenuModules sub = new Business.SubMenuModules();

    List<oSubList> oList = new List<oSubList>();

    int counter = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow nRow in gvModuleList.Rows)
    {
        Int32 intModID = Convert.ToInt32(nRow.Cells[0].Text);
        CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)nRow.FindControl("cbxSelect");

        if (chkBx.Checked == true)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;

            var oModList = sub.GetAllMenuPerModuleID(intModID);

            if (oModList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var rec in oModList)
                {
                    oSubList olist = new oSubList
                    {
                        ID = rec.ID,
                        ModuleID = rec.ModuleID,
                        Submenu = rec.Submenu,
                        Description = rec.Description
                    };
                    oList.Add(olist);    
                }

                Session["list"]=oList;

                SubMenuGrid.DataSource = oList;
                SubMenuGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using:

1. ViewState
2. SessionPageStatePersister
3. Custom Session based solution

For **view state**-see the below posted link in comments..

**Custom Session based solution**

We are going to use the pre render method.
This method is being invoked after the page has been initialized but before it saved its ViewState and rendered.
Are are going to load the Request.Form into a session variable and load it back with each call to the page that is not a postback.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack && Session["PageState"] != null)
   {
    NameValueCollection formValues = (NameValueCollection)Session["PageState"];

    String[] keysArray = formValues.AllKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < keysArray.Length; i++)
    {
      Control currentControl = Page.FindControl(keysArray[i]);
      if (currentControl != null)
      {
        if (currentControl.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)) ((TextBox)currentControl).Text = formValues[keysArray[i]];
        else if (currentControl.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox))
      {
      if (formValues[keysArray[i]].Equals("on")) ((CheckBox)currentControl).Checked = true;
        }
        else if (currentControl.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList))
((DropDownList)currentControl).SelectedValue = formValues[keysArray[i]].Trim();
      }
    }
  }

  if(Page.IsPostBack) Session["PageState"] = Request.Form;

}
```

**SessionPageStatePersister**

The abstract PageStatePersister class represents the base class that encapsulates the Page State storage and processing.
Storage can be done with the default HiddenFieldPageStatePersister class or with SessionPageStatePersister.
When SessionPageStatePersister is used, the .NET Server manages the _VIEWSTATE in a session object instead of a hidden field on your form.
Changing the state storage looks like this:

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement Viewstate to my module? Where do I begin? I can see some sources on Viewstate but I cant apply it to my scenario.

Comment: Do similar to this.. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/viewstate-in-aspnet-with-example-in-c.html